# In virtio, why does guest notifier and host notifier use ioeventfd and irqfd respectively?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-machine, linux-device-driver, kvm

I know that in virtio, when a guest try to notify the host, it writes to a device io address, which causes vm-exit and captured by the hypervisor. The write operation will signal to a eventfd struct, then awake the sleeping vhost_worker thread to deal with the packets in virtqueue.

When the host try to notify the guest, it also uses eventfd to trigger interrupt inject and needs a vm-exit.

My question is: does these two process have to be so complicated? Why don't we just put a eventfd struct into the shared memory between virtio front-end and back-end. Then if a guest try to notify the host, it signals to the eventfd, then the vhost_worker thread is awaken, which seems that we do not need vm-exit. For the guest notifier, it can be done in the same way.
Why can't we notify in this simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: does these two process have to be so complicated?

Short answer: Because virtual machines are complicated. :)

> Why don't we just put a eventfd struct into the shared memory between virtio front-end and back-end.

An eventfd isn't a structure, by the way. It's just an integer, like any other file descriptor.

> Then if a guest try to notify the host, it signals to the eventfd…

It can't do that. Writing to the eventfd would require the guest kernel to make a system call on the host system, which isn't something it has the ability to do. Similarly, the host can't send a signal to an eventfd created by the guest kernel, because the eventfd doesn't exist on the host system.

Keep in mind as well that the guest system might not be running a Linux kernel! The virtio interface is not kernel-specific; it's intended to be applicable to any virtualized OS.